# UINavigationBar titleView for different orientation

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem, titleview

What is the best way to resize UINavigationBar titleview content image when orientation is changed.
I have one image with 44px height and another for 32px and after view is rotated I change the titleview  and set new imageview. but maybe there is another way to  achieve some result by autoresizingmask or some other trick?

Answer (score 1):

The autoresizingMask can modify the size of a view's frame when the device is rotated, but if you want to switch between two different images when the rotation happens you'll have to do it programmatically in `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [super willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation duration:duration];

    if (interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight || interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {        
        // landscape
        [imageView setImage:landscapeImage]; 
    } else {
        // portrait
        [imageView setImage:portraitImage]; 
    }
}
```

Comment: but what way is the best and will not influence on performance ? resize imageview frame by using autoresizing mask or change image ?